# What is the difference between “теперь ещё” and “пока ещё”?

Tags: словоупотребление, выбор-слова

It seems to me that "теперь ещё" and "пока ещё" have very similar meaning.  But I am not sure whether they can always be replaced each other.  For example, does it make any difference if "пока ещё" is replaced by "теперь ещё" in the following second sentence?

Уже не трудно читать русский текст.  Но *пока ещё* трудно говорить правильно.

Comment: I do not see how they can have similar meaning. Could you provide some examples of both? I cannot think of an example where "теперь ещё" is not just two words near each other. In this case "ещё" means "more" ("and now, even more than that ...." / "now, more of..." etc.)

Answer (score 4):

*Пока ещё* = "still" (*пока ещё мы только увеличиваем наши долги*) or "yet" (*пока ещё рано об этом говорить*).

*Теперь ещё* = "now even" (*теперь ещё и со вкусом борща* or *теперь ещё быстрее*). As two separate words *теперь ещё* = "now" + "more" (*расскажите теперь ещё о цене на колбасу*).

In your sentence you can't replace one with another. *Но теперь ещё трудно говорить правильно* would roughly mean "but now it's even difficult to speak correctly" and you wouldn't hear such a construction from a native speaker.

Answer (score 1):

пока ещё = still

теперь ещё = some more now

Answer (score 1):

First of all, "еще" may mean "more", which is the different story.
The second, when referring to time, "пока еще" means "smth. was like this and still is" and "теперь еще" means "now smth. is like this (but earlier it wasn't)". For example, "Я - мужчина, а теперь еще и отец".

Comment: -1 for not using ё in the resource about Russian language

Comment: +1 order to compensate for UVV’s idiosyncrasy.

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov
ххх: передохнем
yyy: это прогноз или тебе было влом до ё тянуться?

Comment: @UVV По правилам, 'ё' совершенно необходимо в случае двусмысленностей, а также в облегченных текстах с проставленными ударениями. В слове «еще» двусмысленностей нет, ударений на RusSE пока никто не ставит (точнее, я не видел). Ответ вполне понятен. К чему придираться?

Comment: Я думаю, в материалах для неносителей придираться стоит. Хотя я бы холивар устраивать тут не стал, скорее просто рекомендовал бы быть внимательнее при наборе примеров для иностранцев.

Comment: @J-mster, ну я, например, систематически ставлю ударения (в т. ч. двоеточие над _е_) в словах и оборотах, что являются предметом обсуждения, но не в тексте, разумеется, даже если он на русском.